# Twilio making call using Dll version 5.3

Tags: c#, twilio, echo, phone-call, twilio-twiml

If we Use the Url as per the Sample Code,it works fine.Here is the Url Used in sample code : ("http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml")
As per the Old Twilio Dll version 3.4 Were making Use of the twimlet Echo to make call i.e("http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%3CSay%3EHi+there.%3C%2FSay%3E%3C%2FResponse%3E"));

And i want to to create to create Stateless apploication,Without application Hosting in any server.

The twimlet echo Url is working fine in version 3.4 and the same URL is not working in 5.3.

```
        const string accountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        const string authToken = "909dajhdusa78798324ndkjsahd";
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var to = new PhoneNumber("+919000000000");
        var from = new PhoneNumber("+919000000000");
        var call = CallResource.Create(to,
                                       from,
                                       url: new Uri("http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=test")); //Not working

        call = CallResource.Create(to,
                                       from,
                                       url: new Uri("http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=<Response><Say>testing</Say></Response>"));//Not working


        call = CallResource.Create(to,
                                       from,
                                       url: new Uri("http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%3CSay%3EHi+there.%3C%2FSay%3E%3C%2FResponse%3E"));//Not working


        Console.WriteLine(call.Sid);
```

Comment: When you say "not working" what are you actually seeing? An error? Can you include the error message? Thanks.

Comment: Call is getting triggered.. But it says Application error

Comment: Can you check the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger) and see what the error is there. Then add that to your question. I might be able to help then.